# An algebra with two multiplications, based on series-parallel diagrams?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, boolean-algebras

Here is a commutative, unital, associative algebra $\mathcal{F}$ with two ways to multiply.  The multiplications come from a construction with Boolean operations and series-parallel diagrams.  I want to know more about $\mathcal{F}$.  Here is my attempt to explain what this is:

Denote the object by $\mathcal{F}$.  A basis for $\mathcal{F}$ consists of 1 and all two-terminal series-parallel diagrams.  This definition is a little troublesome, so I offer some details to clarify what I am talking about.  A two-terminal series-parallel diagram is either
(0) a single segment connecting two terminals,
(1) a join of two smaller two-terminal series-parallel diagrams in series, or
(2) a join of two smaller two-terminal series-parallel diagrams in parallel.
Smallness refers to the number of segments.  For added clarity, note that the number of TTSPD's having $n$ segments is the sequence $A000084$ in the OEIS.  Thus, letting $\mathcal{F}_n$ denote the subspace of $\mathcal{F}$ spanned by those TTSPD's with $n$ segments, the dimension of this subspace is $\dim(\mathcal{F}_n)=(A000084)_n$, if that makes notational sense.

This object $\mathcal{F}$ has two obvious multiplications, given by series connection and parallel connection.  For that matter, there is also an involution, given by employing DeMorgan's Law as follows.  Given a TTSPD $\Delta$, one obtains the dual $\iota(\Delta)$ by exchanging its series and parallel connections.  1 acts as 1 under both multiplications.

There are some other curiosities about $\mathcal{F}$.  It is a unital, associative algebra under either of the two multiplications.  If $\mathbb{F}$ is the underlying field, then $\mathcal{F}$ contains a bunch of copies of $\mathbb{F}[t]$ (polynomials in one variable), using one of the two multiplications.  In any case, it is an algebraic structure that I have not encountered before and I am curious if you know more about it.

The context is geometric combinatorics.  This object $\mathcal{F}$ arises when we try to count lattice points in orthogonal polytopes having a particular specific structure that is probably irrelevant for this question.

Comment: It seems to me that this may just be the free algebra-with-two-commutative-multiplications-with-the-same-identity on one generator.